# Confusingly slow SQL when querying pg_stat_database system view

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I am using PostgreSQL 14.0. When I execute this SQL statement:

```
explain analyse select xact_commit from pg_stat_database;
```

I get a confusing query plan like this:

```
                                    QUERY PLAN:
Subquery Scan on d (cost=0.00..1.11 rows=3 width=8) (actual time-21.502..21.547 rows=8 loops=1)
    -> Append (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=3 width=68) (actual time=0.007..0.046 rows=8 loops=1)
        -> Subquery Scan on"*SELECT* 1" (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
              -> Result (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=1
        -> Seq Scan on pg_database (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=68) (actual time=0.028..0.032 rows=7 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.556 ms
Execution Time: 21.686 ms
7 rows)
```

Why does this SQL query execute so slowly (orders of magnitude slower than querying user tables and other system tables such as `pg_class`) and doesn't use SeqScan directly? Or how can I optimize it?

Comment: Looks like a slow system, mine stays well below 1 millisecond. (by the way, don't use images to explain something, plain text works much better for text)

Answer (score 1):

Takes fractions of a ms on my small test system with few databases.

For what it's worth, like you already mentioned, `pg_stat_database` is a system view - that reports many things with the use of various nested function calls. While you only need `xact_commit`, you can strip the query down to its core:

```sql
SELECT pg_stat_get_db_xact_commit(0) AS xact_commit
UNION ALL 
SELECT pg_stat_get_db_xact_commit(oid) AS xact_commit
FROM   pg_database;
```

Mostly reduces planning time for me. Should be faster in any case. But test and see.